# What is an Oracle Client?

Tags: oracle

I'm from MySQL background and am new to Oracle. I want to know

- What is meant by Oracle Client?
- What is its use?
- What is its equivalent in MySQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

> **What is meant by Oracle Client?**

and

> **What is its use?**

In this context, a client is a class library (DLL) that allows you to connect remotely to the underlying database of an application. A client, always within the same context, can also be called a [`.NET Data Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7ee2dwt(VS.71).aspx).

You may have multiple data providers based on the underlying database engine with which you're working.

There was [`System.Data.OracleClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx) (deprecated), provided by Microsoft.

There is [`Oracle.Data.Client`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/intro003.htm), which is actually the best ever built Oracle Client, or Oracle .NET Data Provider. You may also download the latest [`Oracle 11g Data Provider for .NET`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html).

So, when accessing the Oracle underlying database, make sure your work with this provider, proper for your version of Oracle, and start doing [`ADO.NET`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) with your favorite database! =P

There are also some other tools that you can work with that will ease your data access code pain, such as [`Enterprise Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) or [`NHibernate`](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), both are frameworks to basically accessing databases.

[`Enterprise Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) can do even more then that!

And [`NHibernate`](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) is an [`ORM (Object/Relation Mapping)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool that can work just very fine with Oracle.

Remember though, always use [`Oracle.Data.Client`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/intro003.htm) namespace in the [`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) assembly.

> **What is its equivalent in MySQL ?**

As the equivalence for MySQL, I guess it would be [`MySQL Connector/NET`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html).

Comment: Good explanation. I used to use the separate Oracle-provided assembly on an older project, but switched to the .NET-bundled version when the project was updated to .NET 2.0. Now I gotta switch it back...*grumble*

Comment: Yes, the `System.Data.OracleClient` had a funny behaviour sometimes. We were using it too on a big project, until some troubles come out with the underlying Oracle database. We did some researches, and found out that some lacks of performance were due to the Microsoft Oracle Client. We have then switched to `Oracle Native Client`, and some of the troubles went away just like by magic! =) Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Why is this answer entirely .Net-centric? There have been Oracle clients since before .Net was ever dreamed of!

Comment: Right! But in today's development .NET occupies a great market, with Sun Java technologies. As I'm a .NET developer, I went .NET. You can post your own answer so that we all might benefit of your contribution, instead of arguing (no harm meant here). =)

Comment: There is `Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client ` from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html. Does that mean the ado.net connector is as huge as 615 mb?

Comment: Then why drivers are required like ODBC for the communication? Does the driver too bundled in Oracle client?

Comment: Please update this to reference the fact that Oracle now provides an
 official build of the managed client on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/. Also, the managed client has one fairly major downside: it doesn't work if your Oracle database (yes, the database server, *not* the client) is less than 12.1 (I think it was fixed in 12.1, might be 12.2) and you enable Windows' FIPS mode.

Answer (score 11):

It is the Oracle binaries installed that allow communication with the Oracle database. It can be using SQL*Plus, JDBC (type II or IV) or OCI (Oracle Call Interface).

Comment: SQL*Plus goes through the OCI.
'Installing' the instantclient is just an unzip operation, which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Pro*C/C++ programs are written using OCI to interact with the database.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_access.htm#sthref3719

Could even go as far as including ODBC as an 'Oracle client'.

Comment: The JDBC, ODBC, and OLE DB drivers, and the .Net Data Provider are all wrappers around OCI.

Answer (score 7):

Its a piece of software that allows a remote computer to talk to Oracle.  If you were to write a piece of software that communicated with the database, you would use the Oracle Client to facilitate that communication